# Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have the following vb statement at Microsoft Access 2010

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table3(Names,ID, center, village, association , BOD ) " & _
  " VALUES(" & Me.fullnametxt & ",'" & Me.worktxt & "','" & _
  Me.Combo39 & "','" & Me.assoctxt & "','" & Me.datetraintxt & "','" & Me.datetraintxt & "')"
```

It generates

> Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: Look at your string again closely, I would review where your `'` are at. I would also look into parameters as well to help prevent SQL Injection... It would also prevent mistakes like you are having right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You miss some quotes:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table3 ( Names, ID, center, village, association , BOD ) " & _
  " VALUES ('" & Me.fullnametxt & "','" & Me.worktxt & "','" & _
  Me.Combo39 & "','" & Me.assoctxt & "','" & Me.datetraintxt & "','" & Me.datetraintxt & "')"
```